# Bootstrap v3.2 nav-list - hover style stays - ie9

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

So I am using bootstrap to generate a hover style when hovering over a navbar link. This works fine until you use IE9 and are too fast, the style stays "hovered", even when not hovering the item anymore.

Like this I can get multiple items in my menu in the "hovered" style which shouldn't be happening.

My code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
    <!-- ko foreach: router.activeItem().sidebar.links -->
       <li data-bind="visible: visible" class="special">
           <a data-bind="attr: { href: hash, title: title }"
              data-toggle="tooltip"
              data-placement="right">
                   <i class="menu-icon fa fa-5x" data-bind="css: icon"></i>
           </a>
        </li>
     <!-- /ko -->
 </ul>
```

The bug:

[image]

I have tried alot of things like adding another class like this:

```
.noHoverForThis {
color: inherit !important;
}
```

This does not work for some reason.
Same for overriding the whole bootstrap class didn't work for me, unless I failed hard writing this...

```
.navbar .nav-list > li:hover > a, 
.navbar .nav-list > li > a:hover {
    background-color: #e7e7e7 !important;
    color: inherit !important;
}
```

Keep in mind the bug only occurs in IE9.

Any help would be very welcome!

**EDIT:** Interesting to know: I am using ACE Theme 
[www.wrapbootstrap.com](http://www.wrapbootstrap.com)

Comment: You are unable to upgrade to Bootstrap v3?

Comment: I am using Bootstrap V3.2 (your edit to the title was incorrect ;-) ), will this help me in a way?

Comment: There's no `nav-list` in Bootstrap 3, so what you're dealing with isn't a standard Bootstrap widget, it's some custom widget.

Comment: I guess it's part of the ACE Theme then I guess. I finally found the issue. Thanks for trying to assist in this matter!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured it out.

The code that should be used to fix this issue and override the hover state is:

```
.no-skin .nav-list > li:hover > a {
    background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248) !important;
    color: #585858 !important;
}

.nav-list > li::before {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

And then include it in the `Index.cshtml` of durandal

```
    <!--[if lte IE 9]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/IEHacks.css" />
    <![endif]-->
```

This will override the hover of the ace theme using bootstrap v3.2